# Rellenar select con datos Json

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax

venía a ver si alguien que se maneje mejor con ajax puede ayudarme

estoy intentando según el valor de el cuadro desplegable pais me muestre las ciudades de ese mismo pais, paso a incluir el codigo y los errores.
aquí el codigo de el controlador:

```
 public function paisesAjax($pais){
    $destinos=DB::table('destinations')->where('country',$pais)->get();
    return $destinos->toJson();

}
```

y por aquí el codigo ajax en el formulario

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#pais').on('change', function () {
    var pais = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'paisesAjax/'+pais,
        datatype: "JSON",
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
            if(res){
                $("#city1").empty();
                $.each(res, function (i, p) {
                    $('#city1').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
                })
            }
        }

    });
})
```

El error que me mustra en la consola es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano a todos, creo que estoy cerca de sacarlo, pero no llego a dar con el error..

Comment: Hola, con tu codigo actual estas intentando que el valor de la opcion del select sea un json y no un valor en si. Unicamente deberias cambiar la linea dentro de tu each por la siguiente: `$('#city1').append($('<option></option>').val(p.id).html(p.city));`. De todas formas hice un https://jsfiddle.net/michoacano094/gyfu4man como ejemplo.

Comment: muchisimas gracias @EstebanJuarez lo solucioné en su momento justo de la forma que dices, muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda amigo, si lo pones como respuesta te la marco como respuesta correcta ;)